# How can I make nested loop by using only one for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I saw this code from stack overflow

```
int[,] matrix = new int[5, 10];     
int row = matrix.GetLength(0);
int col = matrix.GetLength(1);      

for (int i = 0; i < row * col; i++)
{
    matrix[i / col , i % col] = i + 1;
}
```

and someone say that it`ll make nested loop.
I was trying to crack this code, but I cannot.
somebody please explain how this code works.

Comment: What's the benefits of avoiding nested loop ?

Comment: @SteveB In this case, none. But in some cases it can linearise access to the underlying, contiguous storage. It’s a fairly common technique in C++ to implement multi-dimensional arrays as a 1D vector. I believe the same might be true in C# when performing pixel-level image manipulation (conceivably when implementing image filters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this code has no nested loop, per se. However, it counts from `0` to `5 * 10 - 1`, and in each iteration calculates the row and column indexes. The following is probably better understandable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row * col; i++)
{
    int rowIndex = i / col; // divide by column count = row index
    int colIndex = i % col; // modulo by column count = column index
    Console.WriteLine($"i: {i} => row: {rowIndex}, col: {colIndex}");
    matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] = i + 1;
}
```

Write down the actual numbers and you will see for yourself that for iterations `0` to `9` you will get `rowIndex == 0` and `colIndex` having values `0` to `9`, then for iterations `10` to `19` you get `rowIndex == 1` and `colIndex` having values `0` to `9` etc.

A nested-loop variant would, naturally, look like this:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++)
{
  for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < col; colIndex++)
  {
    int i = rowIndex * col + colIndex; // back-calculate 'i'
    Console.WriteLine($"i: {i} => row: {rowIndex}, col: {colIndex}");
    matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] = i + 1;
}
```

The one-loop version has the nested look *unrolled* and replaced with mathematical operations (division, modulo) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two nested `for` loops, one from 0 to `row` and one from 0 to `col`, the two loops will together execute `row * col` times. So you can replace the nested loops by a single loop that runs from 0 to `row * col`, and that’s exactly what’s been done here.

The only thing you need to do then is to find the separate loop indices of the nested loops (let’s call them `j` and `k`) from the single loop index `i`.

The way to do this is to consider a `row * col` table filled with the numbers 0…`row * col`. How do we find the row and column index (`j` and `k`, respectively) for a given entry `i`? Well, the code you’ve posted tells us:

```
int j = i / col // row index
int k = i % col // col index
```